# Why am I getting "Failed to set remote video description send parameters for m-section with mid='0'" error in Android when it works in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, java, android, socket.io, webrtc

##### Background Information

Hi there, I am attempting to build a WebRTC client in Android that subscribes to a video feed that is being broadcast using NodeJS and JavaScript.

The broadcaster code can be viewed in its entirety [in this lovely article by Gabriel Tanner](https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/webrtc-video-broadcast).

It works beautifully when running it in localhost under the `http://localhost:4000/broadcaster.html` in Chrome and then visiting my IP Address from another device on the network. I can see the video and it is near real time.

I have tried this using two different webcam devices, both a built-in and a USB webcam but the Android client does not work even though the JavaScript Broadcaster and Client works fine.

##### The task at hand

After following the tutorial and getting the example to work I decided to try and implement my own Android application for which the entire source code can be viewed [right here on my GitHub](https://github.com/JohanJarvi/AndroidWebRTCClient).

I have followed various tutorials around the place and the issue always stems from attempting to set the remote description which is done with the following bit of code:

```java
    private void setRemoteDescription(Object[] arguments) {
        JSONObject message = (JSONObject) arguments[1];
        try {
            String sdp = message.getString("sdp");
            SessionDescription sessionDescription = new SessionDescription(OFFER, sdp);
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "setRemoteDescription: failed to parse JSON", e);
        }
    }
```

Like I said the full code can be viewed in the GitHub and I don't want to clutter this post too much but essentially as per Gabriel's tutorial when the socket emits "watcher" upon connection (which the Android App does correctly) it will then send back an "offer" which is then listened for on the client side like this:

```java
    private void bindSocketEvents() {
        socket.on(EVENT_CONNECT, args -> {
            socket.emit("watcher");
        }).on("broadcaster", args -> {
            socket.emit("watcher");
        }).on("offer", args -> {
            setRemoteDescription(args);
            performAnswer();
        }).on("candidate", this::addIceCandidate);
    }
```

Where we then see that upon "offer" we call the code with the args from JavaScript and attempts to set the Remote Description but it fails to do so.

This is an example SDP that I get from triggering this:

```
v=0
o=- 7040957491050894781 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS l91G3Ekmme9tlvEso1ApTqS6djaxtsamgfLu
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 121 127 120 125 107 108 109 35 36 124 119 123
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:XEnc
a=ice-pwd:2PyQmLOm9YPPf1Pozvonticd
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 64:22:D7:93:FD:6C:A9:94:E3:65:76:B0:DB:4E:E9:8E:91:46:56:87:B1:E3:E9:B3:24:D0:CF:A5:3F:91:0A:FD
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:4 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendrecv
a=msid:l91G3Ekmme9tlvEso1ApTqS6djaxtsamgfLu 7eb4296c-f3e4-4e95-9f6f-05aa386a3176
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:35 AV1X/90000
a=rtcp-fb:35 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:35 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:35 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack pli
a=rtpmap:36 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:36 apt=35
a=rtpmap:124 red/90000
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 4173041010 2470630943
a=ssrc:4173041010 cname:VrEB0NYLt23UUzRD
a=ssrc:4173041010 msid:l91G3Ekmme9tlvEso1ApTqS6djaxtsamgfLu 7eb4296c-f3e4-4e95-9f6f-05aa386a3176
a=ssrc:4173041010 mslabel:l91G3Ekmme9tlvEso1ApTqS6djaxtsamgfLu
a=ssrc:4173041010 label:7eb4296c-f3e4-4e95-9f6f-05aa386a3176
a=ssrc:2470630943 cname:VrEB0NYLt23UUzRD
a=ssrc:2470630943 msid:l91G3Ekmme9tlvEso1ApTqS6djaxtsamgfLu 7eb4296c-f3e4-4e95-9f6f-05aa386a3176
a=ssrc:2470630943 mslabel:l91G3Ekmme9tlvEso1ApTqS6djaxtsamgfLu
a=ssrc:2470630943 label:7eb4296c-f3e4-4e95-9f6f-05aa386a3176
```

#### The error

Now the thing is that when I try and set this remote description these errors get thrown and we never get to attempt to `peerConnection.createAnswer`:

```
2021-11-12 13:45:52.819 26795-27780/au.com.australiandroid.androidclient D/CustomPeerConnectionObs: onSignalingChange: new signaling state is HAVE_REMOTE_OFFER
2021-11-12 13:45:52.820 26795-27780/au.com.australiandroid.androidclient E/SimpleSdpObserver: onSetFailure: failed to set the remote description: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters for m-section with mid='0'.
2021-11-12 13:45:52.820 26795-27780/au.com.australiandroid.androidclient E/MainActivity: onCreateFailure: failed to create answer: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set remote video description send parameters for m-section with mid='0'..
```

If you have any information whatsoever as to why it fails to setRemoteDescription or even if you have any advice regarding how to implement an Android WebRTC client then anything would be helpful at this point. I have struggled for weeks and I don't know where to go from here because Googling this error isn't helping. Either because I simply do not understand the answer or because the answer isn't relevant. I don't know but please don't just paste a link to the top hit on Google because I have read so many of them.

Comment: does this go away if you remove the H264 codecs from the offer? You might be hitting an instance of https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=9774

Comment: I haven’t attempted to remove the H264 codecs from the offer. Have you got any information on how to do that? I can Google it myself otherwise. Thanks for the hint. It seems that chromium bug was closed off as a versioning issue but I’m using the latest version of WebRTC SDK on  Android [as per this website](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/) and likely the very latest version of chrome. So - I don’t think it’s due to the libraries being old but I’ll look into the H264 thing.

Comment: replacing all instances of the string "H264" with "this-codec-is-not-supported" should be sufficient for a first test.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice Philipp. Your advice led me down a track of pursuing hardware encoding and led me to discovering that there was an error with my peer connection factory which resulted in me not having properly enabled Hardware Encoding/Decoding on the Android client side. Once I did those fixes it led me down a road of a mountain of other bugs and issues but eventually resulted in me having a working solution. I will answer my own question with the exact process when I get the time. But thank you for your advice, it was what led me to the answer.

Comment: it is always h264 hardware encoding :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message was triggered due to the offer containing H264 codecs whilst the Android Client was not anticipating H264 and was not setup to encode and/or decode this particular hardware encoded stream.

The fix was to ensure that the connection factory was setup as such:

```java
    private void createPeerConnectionFactory() {
        PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
                PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this)
                        .createInitializationOptions();

        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);
        PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();

        VideoEncoderFactory encoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), true, true);
        VideoDecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());

        peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                .setOptions(options)
                .setVideoDecoderFactory(decoderFactory)
                .setVideoEncoderFactory(encoderFactory)
                .createPeerConnectionFactory();

        List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
        PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);
        createPeerConnection(rtcConfig);
    }
```

Where the `rootEglBase` was setup earlier by defining a variable in the activity like `private EglBase rootEglBase;` and following that up with creating a new instance of it with `EglBase.create()` in the Activities `onCreate` method.

The actual winning lines in the `peerConnectionFactory` was defining the `encoderFactory` and the `decoderFactory` and specifying the correct flags to tell WebRTC that we want to use h264HighProfile.

This is seen in this line:
        `VideoEncoderFactory encoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), true, true);`

Where the first `true` boolean is to enable *VP8* encoding and the second is for *H264*.

Once this was set correctly it would accept the offer when attempting to `setRemoteDescription` and it lead me down the right track in order to solve many of the other problems that were still in my code.

So if you are getting that same error message chances are it's because of some form of hardware encoding possibly to do with H264.

If you find this question and my answer and it not quite making sense then just shoot me a PM or comment on this answer and I'll try my best to help you get it working as well.

Comment: Man I wish I had found your posts half a year ago!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue receiving a webrtc stream within a WebView, though I'm not sure how to proceed since I don't think I can set the encoder/decoder. I tried enabling HW acceleration for the app, to no avail.

Comment: @Lior you could try and manually manipulate the SDP. If you look at my original question you see that I provide an SDP; and some of the comments are talking about removing certain encoders/decoders from the SDP itself. Not sure what your code looks like but I'm assuming that you would have the Server in JavaScript and so then [this article might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857702/split-sdp-string-for-m-line-to-change-video-codecs).

Comment: Also @Lior; not sure about your background but if you are perhaps new to WebRTC then the [MDN WebRTC API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) are very useful and particularly perhaps the [description of the SDP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Protocols#sdp) could be useful to you.